# GL20.glCompileShader crashingly Java program using OpenGL

Tags: java, macos, opengl, shader

I am getting the following error code when trying to run my Java application using OpenGL on MacOS:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff6ac1fd2d, pid=2068, tid=0x0000000000001903

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [libsystem_platform.dylib+0x1d2d]  _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Haswell+0x4d
```

The erroneous code is describe below. By inspection, I have determined that the Line that is crashing my program is `GL20.glCompileShader(shaderID);`
The full code is below:

```
private static int loadShader(String file, int type) {
    StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            shaderSource.append(line).append("//\n");
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    int shaderID = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
    GL20.glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);
    GL20.glCompileShader(shaderID);
    if (GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
        System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, 500));
        System.err.println("Could not compile shader!");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    return shaderID;
    //return 5;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, no gl-command can crash an app. I suggest to use a debugger and watch the stack when the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

just by looking on the code everything should be alright. since there is no GL_INVALID in your errorlog, i assume something is wrong with import or requirements.

if u dont use a debugger, which you should, use `System.out` to check what glCreateShader returned.